# What am I missing in GotW #28: The Fast Pimpl Idiom?

Tags: c++

"[GotW #28](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/028.htm)" is an old article written by Herb Sutter. In that article, Herb explains why the following design is a bad idea (I took the liberty to replace `assert` with `static_assert`, though):

```
// file y.h
class Y
{
    /*...*/
    static const size_t sizeofx = /*some value*/;
    char x_[sizeofx];
};

// file y.cpp
#include "x.h"

Y::Y() {
    static_assert( sizeofx >= sizeof(X), "Please, fix Y::sizeofx" );
    new (&x_[0]) X;
}

Y::~Y()
{
    (reinterpret_cast<X*>(&x_[0]))->~X();
}
```

Leaving aside the questions of alignment (`std::aligned_storage` wasn't around at the time) and maintenance, I'd like to focus on the following point:

Herb Sutter claims that writing a safe (considering exception safety) `Y::operator=()` and safe `Y::~Y()` is a lot more trouble than it's worth. **And this is something I don't get.**

What trouble is he talking about? What's wrong with the destructor above? And what's wrong with a simple assignment like this:

```
Y& Y::operator=(const Y& other)
{
    *reinterpret_cast<X*>(&x_[0]) = *reinterpret_cast<const X*>(&other.x_[0]);
    return *this;
}
```

Given that `Y` class has neither base classes no other members, I would say that exception guarantees of `Y::operator=(const Y&)` and `Y::~Y()` will be those of corresponding `X::operator=(const X&)` and `X::~X()`. But Herb Sutter hinted that there's more trouble to it...

**What am I missing?**

Comment: I can't speak to exception-safety issues, but one downside of this approach is that if you need to change `sizeofx`, then `sizeof Y` will likely change also, which means that any binaries that use `class Y` will need to be recompiled in order to work correctly with the new `class Y`.  This obviates one of the advantages of Pimpl, which is the ability to modify a class's internal implementation without forcing a rebuild of all the code that references/uses the class.

Comment: Try writing (defining) a `Y::operator=()` with the assumption that `X::operator=()` may throw an exception.   Also, although `std::aligned_storage` wasn't around, alignment of types was an important consideration, and the code as shown tramples all over that.

Comment: @Peter, I did that. It's the second code snippet, right in the question. If `X::operator=()` throws an exception it will fly through `Y::operator=()` as-is, and reach the client code. Sorry, I still fail to see what's wrong with that. Could you please explain? Are you assuming that `Y::operator=()` should be `noexcept`? From my point of view it shouldn't. An assignment operator that throws looks perfectly normal to me.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, you're right: exposing the size of the implementation class introduces a build dependency. But that's not a problem in my case. In fact, I _need_ the client code to know the memory footprint of the class and recompile each time it changes.

Comment: @IgorG - you're assuming `Y::operator=()` is all or nothing - it either succeeds and doesn't throw, or it throws and otherwise has no effect.   Consider what happens if you need to provide a strong exception guarantee and `Y` contains a number of members that must each be assigned, and any of those assignments after the first may throw.

Comment: @Peter, right! But Y _always_ contains only one member :- ) That's one of the key points of the Pimpl idiom. And Herb's remark about there being 'a lot more trouble' was also about this specific case: no base subobjects, only one data member. So I want to get to the bottom of this particular case, not just any possible `Y` with arbitrary members.

Comment: @Igor -  Sorry - typo.   I was referring to `X` containing more than one member, not `Y`.   (When typing previous comment, my mind somehow went to `X` containing `Y` rather than - as in your question - `Y` containing `X`).

Comment: @Peter, Oh, no problem! But then that's not a trouble with `Y` (the facade class), is it? It's about implementing `X` (the inner class) properly. So I assume that whoever implements `X` knows what copy-and-swap is...